# How to store save the date along with time in SharePoint list DateTime field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to store date along with the time in SharePoint list using the Rest API
How should I convert ("28-02-2018 12:43 PM") to date and time format using the jquery. and How should I store it into the SharePoint list

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a date time column in your list to be able to store date time values. Next, while doing POST to create list item, convert the date time value to [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) format and then call the REST API. Sample JS code given below.

```
var d = new Date();
d.toISOString();
```

You can also check [this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328025.aspx#BKMK_UpdatingDateValues) which does the same thing as `toISOString()`.